# PHP Compare Array Keys In Loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a while loop like below. I want to sum all of the fields from the database, but ignore a set few. These are called id, summary and diff.

I have setup what I think I need below, but do not know how to compare the current key to these field names correctly.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table';
$result = mysql_query($sql)
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
//DOES KEY = an ignore field name?

//If No 
$i++
}
```

Comment: Why not just select the fields you _are_ looking for from the database?

Comment: You can store ignored fields in an array then check if key is in array with this function : http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php , but don't do this unless you have a good reason, do what andrewsi says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ignoreTheseColumns = array("id", "summary", "diff");
$sum = 0;
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table';
$result = mysql_query($sql)
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    foreach($row as $key=>$value)
    {
        //DOES KEY = an ignore field name?
        if(!in_array($key, $ignoreTheseColumns))
        {
            $sum+= $value
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the relevant ones from the query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `key` NOT IN ('id','summary','diff')
```

Alternatively, you can just use an `if` statement in your PHP:

```
if($row['key'] == 'id' || $row['key'] == 'summary' || $row['key'] == 'diff') continue;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `in_array`. `if(in_array($row[i], $values)` you will have to do a loop in the row to search each column. Just build an array of all the fields you want to search